# Can we access YouTube Analytics Metrics (Impressions, Impressions CTR) from API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the impressions data using the API. Are these available yet through APIs?

I don't see these in the metrics as well. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Comment: I still have hope they have it somewhere, but I couldn't find it yet either. https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics

Comment: [@kangkyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622415/kangkyu) [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490683) on an identical StackOverflow question solves this problem.