# Google API to get impressions of youtube videos?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

Is there any API available to fetch **Impressions** of a youtube video? or the Impressions of all the videos in a account?

*Note: I'm looking for video thumbnail impressions and not (card or annotation impressions)*

Sample:
This 1.9M is the data I'm interested in this video

[image]

Comment: It looks like a youtube-analytics-api feature not a youtube-data-api. If you don't have help there, come back I have a medium difficulty workaround.

Comment: Changed the tag 

Comment: @ArunJoseph This information is not available via the Analytics API.

Comment: Do u have any idea how to get this data? (:

Comment: @ArunJoseph I don't have the data to try it, but, have you checked the network tab and see which kind of data is sent and see if you can request such endpoints (*if any*)?

Comment: Note that [I significantly updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71490683/revisions), as [@MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12511801/marco-aurelio-fernandez-reyes) described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always YouTube APIs doesn't provide access to a basic feature but here is a workaround:

The following answer is similar to [the one I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71987890) about retrieving `Unique viewers` from the `Audience` tab.

Go on your [Video analytics interface](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-default) in YouTube Studio.

Open the `Web Developer Tools` `Network` tab of your web-browser (by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> on Firefox for instance).

Now select `Reach`, pay attention to select one of following:

- [First 24 hours](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-since_publish,time_period_unit_nth_days,1)
- [Last 7 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-week)
- [Last 28 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-4_weeks)
- [Last 90 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-quarter)
- [Last 365 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-year)
- [Since uploaded (lifetime)](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-lifetime)

Because options:

- [Since published](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-reach_viewers/period-since_publish)
- Others depending on the time of video upload

Are maybe unavailable (depends if its a published video or depends on the time of video upload):

> Total number of unique viewers is only available for periods of up to
> 90 days to ensure data quality.

You should see a request to `get_screen`, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking).

Pay attention to remove `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'` from it in order to get the JSON response in a human readable format. Otherwise you would face the following warning:

> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output " to save to a file.

In `--data-raw` request argument `--data-raw '{"screenConfig":{"entity":{"videoId":"VIDEO_ID"}` pay attention to change the `VIDEO_ID` for the one interesting you.

Execute the modified cURL request and your `Impressions` and `Impressions click-through rate` values are in the JSON response respectively at the keys `/cards/0/keyMetricCardData/keyMetricTabs/{0,1}/primaryContent/total`.

Comment: Incredible answer. Thank you