# How can we pull video_id wise subscribers gain and loss as it shown to youtube's analytics section under overview using Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to to fetch youtube video_id wise subscribers, impression, etc. But could not find any method under the API docs. It would be great a help if someone can explain some alternative if I a missing something here.

Required format:

video_id | Subscriber gain | SUbscriber Loss| Impression | CTR ....
iwhriwfb | 30              | 1.              |30000.     |2%

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490683) will help you to some extent.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Thanks, However I figured out with some other way. But I can see impression and CTR values are still coming incorrect (i.e Zero).

Comment: They are incorrect with your or my method?

Comment: Since I am directly calling youtube analytics API...Values are zero there. I saw your solution which is very smart , I must say, However I need to figure out, How I should be integrating with the existing codes. As I have multiple channels and thousands of videos. Thanks @BenjaminLoison